# ¿Qué significa "confiamos haberle ofrecido un buen servicio"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Viajé alguna vez con Iberia y la sobrecargo dijo al final:

> "Gracias por viajar con Iberia. **Confiamos** haberle ofrecido un buen servicio"

Quizá me maravilla que la traducción que después ella pronunció en inglés del texto en negritas haya sido: **we trust**. Normalmente alguien que ofrece un servicio diría *esperamos haber ofrecido* o algo así.

¿Qué acepción de *confiar* es esta?

Answer (score 5):

Dadas estas dos posibles frases:

> Confiamos haberle ofrecido un buen servicio.
>
> Esperamos haberle ofrecido un buen servicio.

La segunda da más claramente la idea de seguridad de parte de quien la dice:

> Estar confiado de algo <==> Tener la confianza en ese algo.

Esto último, es mucho más "fuerte" que el simple **esperar** que algo sea como se supone que debiera haber sido.

Según la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/confiar):

> 4. intr. Esperar con firmeza y seguridad. U. t. c. prnl.

Answer (score 2):

La palabra *confiamos* aquí significa "creemos con confianza que le ofrecimos un buen servicio".

Denota que están satisfechos y orgullosos del servicio que te ofrecieron, pero a la vez también da la posibilidad de que no estés de acuerdo con ellos.

Answer (score 2):

Las dos frases tienen el mismo significado. Pero a veces se usa "confiamos ..." frente a "esperamos...", porque "esperamos..." tiene una doble acepción, una de las cuales falsearía el mensaje que se pretende comunicar.

Quizás la sobrecargo del vuelo es de origen catalán, donde se ve un poco más claro.

Esta doble acepción de "esperamos" es la de "es de esperar", y sugiere que la persona que emite la frase, en el caso de ejemplo la sobrecargo de vuelo, "espera" de los pasajeros que hagan una valoración favorable del servicio prestado. La implicación es como en "no espero menos de ustedes", o en "no me fallen!".

Con la segunda acepción de "esperamos", en caso de valoración negativa del servicio, se traslada la culpa a los pasajeros. O puede entenderse así.

Si la sobrecargo dice "esperamos haberles ofrecido un buen servicio" todos la entenderán, muy probablemente, igual que si dice "confíamos haberles ofrecido un buen servicio".

Pero en la mente del que lo pronuncia, especialmente quien quiere hacer sentir a sus clientes como que han sido tratados como reyes, que se sientan mimados, prefieren evitar susceptibilidades con la doble acepción de "esperamos" (de ustedes que sepan valorar lo recibido).

Es un poco extremo, pero es casi subconsciente. Quien quiere "servir" intenta evitar "disgustos" donde quiera que el otro pueda encontrarlos.

Al elegir la forma "confiamos haberles ofrecido un buen servicio" la sobrecargo hace dos cosas: evita que el pasajero se sienta empujado (se espera de él) a dar una valoración positiva; y reconoce el poder del usuario a la hora de valorar el servicio ofrecido, transmitiéndole, al reconocerlo, que ha estado obrando para satisfacerle, es decir, con espíritu de servicio (no con espíritu de "y ahora que ya les hemos ofrecido tantas cosas, espero de ustedes que digan que les ha gustado ... vamos, es lo mínimo!"). (por exagerar).

Comment: Quizás se entienda mejor si digo que "esperamos que ..." se puede entender como "We expect ...".