# Recursos que comparen el español de España y el sudamericano

Tags: hispanoamérica, recursos

Aprendí el español con una profesora madrileña, pero vivo en las Américas y mis amigos hispanohablantes son todos de Sudamérica así que ahora mi español es una mezcla de español de España y otros dialectos de México o Argentina.

Estoy buscando recursos en internet que aclaren las mayores diferencias entre esos dialectos para mejorar mi español idiomático y finalmente poder expresarme de manera consistente.

**Más específicamente:**

- Lo más importante es la conjugación de verbos (vos *vs* tu *vs* usted, están *vs* estáis etc) y vocabulario (coche *vs* carro, pastel *vs* postre *vs* torta, estación *vs* temporada, etc).
- Me interesa más el español de México y Perú.

*Please feel free to correct my terrible Spanish*

Comment: Nice question, but note this is a bit off topic. See [What are some good online resources we can use?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/74/1674)

Comment: Esos amigos hispanohablantes tuyos son de hecho el mejor recurso. No entiendo lo de "exprimirme de manera consistente" (querías decir "expresarme")? Creo que va a haber poca consistencia si por ejemplo uno de esos dialectos usa el voseo rioplatense y otros no. A la postre, y especialmente si ya se mezclan varios dialectos en tu grupo de amigos, el tuyo, sea de donde sea, es tan bueno como los otros. Por qué no ser tú el que tiene el español castellano en un grupo donde ya hay español mejicano, peruano y/o argentino?

Comment: @Diego Esto es exactamente el problema: puedo entender los otros idiomas, así  mezclando lo que escucho con lo que aprendí, por ejemplo: ustedes estáis. Quizás se entiende, pero no me gusta.

Comment: @fedorqui anything I can do to get it on-topic ? narrow it down more maybe ?

Comment: They are not dialects.

Comment: @c.p., what are they then?

Comment: Checking [What topics can I ask about here?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I see _Dialect differences_, so you can ask for some specific cases. What is not on topic is to ask for resources. From that page: _But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site. ----> Questions seeking learning resources_

Comment: @Diego El español de México y el de Argentina son variaciones del español, no son dialectos (que es lo que me parece que el OP decía antes de la edición). Hay muchas palabras que han sido tomadas de los dialectos, del inca "papa" en vez de "patata", o "tomate" del nahuatl, etc. Pero eso no lo hace cada español hablado en América Latina otro idioma y mucho menos un dialecto. Si ellos fuesen dialectos, también todo lo que se habla en España, al no ser más uniforme que lo que se habla en AL, también sería una colección de dialectos...

Comment: ..., pero no lo es (aunque a veces pienso lo contrario, [como al escuchar el mal uso de la palabra confiar](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14846/qu%C3%A9-significa-confiamos-haberle-ofrecido-un-buen-servicio)).